# Stack Activity: Last activity of every question

Tags: script

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​[image: main]

[image][image: Install userscript][image][image: View source]
[image][image: compatibility][image][image: MIT License]

Comment: @CodyGuldner What do you mean by "active" sidebar thing?

Comment: On the sidebar of every question, just above the section that has questions that are "linked" or "related", it has a line that says "active: " then a link to the last thing that was done for the question

Comment: @CodyGuldner I guess [this is what you mean](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3QMeY.png). The purpose of this script is to make it easier for people to identify questions of interest *before* they click on the link to it. The benefit of implementing this may not be enough to justify the surge in API usage when every question triggers a call to the API.